# Run rails migration file from controller action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, migration

I have this rails migration file(123blablabla.rb) that I would like to run on create and on update actions. How do I got about it.

**Migration:**

```
class CombineItemsInSale < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]
  def up
    Sale.all.each do |sale|
      sums = sale.items.group(:product_id).sum(:quantity)
      sums.each do |product_id, quantity|
        if quantity > 1
          sale.items.where(product_id: product_id).delete_all

          item = sale.items.build(product_id: product_id)
          item.quantity = quantity
          item.save!
        end
      end
    end
  end

  def down
    #split items with a quantity of 1 or more into multiple items
    Item.where("quantity>1").each do |item|
      item.quantity.times do
        Item.create(
          sale_id: item.sale_id,
          product_id: item.product_id,
          quantity: 1
        )
      end
      # remove original line item
      item.destroy
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Why would you want to run a migration? A migration should be creating/updating your database schema, why would you want to do this now? If you're using a migration to do some advanced data manipulation, pull that code into a helper/lib class and call it from your migration and also from your controller.

Comment: What do you want to achieve? It is a very bad idea to use migrations this way

Comment: I have a product, item, and sale models. An item belongs to product, belongs to sale. A sale has several items, so I would like to combine items with similar product_id into one and sum up their quantity.  I did this in a migration by creating a combineitems migration and it worked. But can't figure out how to call every time user creates or updates sale.

Answer (score 0):

Migrations are used to alter your database schema over time, you should not use the migrations this way.

First thing first please update your question, your question should be  because what you are asking right now is not making any sense and people will get confused.

Now coming back to the topic

You should update your model on transactional basis instead of running process over all of the data.
Every time Item is created/updated use call back to split the

```
class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to sale
  after_commit :split
  ...
  def split
    self.sale.split_items
  end
end

class Sale < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many items
  ...
  def split_items
    products_items = self.items.group_by(&:product_id)
    products_items.each do |product_id, items|
      if items > 1
        quantity = items.sum(:quantity)
        items.delete_all
        Item.create(product_id: product_id, quantity:quantity)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

**Note** This this not the optimal way to do it, but it will do the work.

Answer (score 0):

***For someone need to run migration using controller. I got some solutions.***

```rb
  def action
    ActiveRecord::Base.connection.migration_context.run(:down, 20220704153032)
    ActiveRecord::Base.connection.migration_context.run(:up, 20220704153032)
  end
```

`20220704153032`is Version number of migration file.